# Bulk/batch search in MySql using JPA/Native query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have a MySQL database table with 10 million entities. I have to search for entities with multiple parameters.
Example:

select * from result_table where roll=12345 and reg=6789 and exam='ABC';

I'm looking for an efficient way to batch entity search using JPA or native query using a single query or any other optimized option.
Example:

```
select * from result_table where roll=1234 and reg=1234 and exam='ABC';
select * from result_table where roll=1234 and reg=1234 and exam='DEF';
select * from result_table where roll=2222 and reg=3333 and exam='XYZ';
```

Mysql IN Operator doesn't resolve my issue because roll and reg can be same in different exam. Thank you.

Comment: To improve shown queries create composite index by a combination of all 2 columns used in WHERE in any order. `CREATE INDEX idx ON result_table (roll, reg, exam);`

Comment: roll+reg+exam unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this,

create table

```
create table Test(id integer,roll integer, reg integer, exam varchar(100));
```

insert records

```
insert into Test(id,roll,reg, exam) values(1,1234,1234, "ABC");

insert into Test(id,roll,reg, exam) values(1,1234,1234, "DEF");

insert into Test(id,roll,reg, exam) values(1,2222,3333, "XYZ");
```

select query

```
select * from Test where CONCAT(roll,reg,exam) in ('12341234ABC','12341234DEF','22223333XYZ');
```

Comment: CONCAT(1234,1234,'ABC')=CONCAT(123,41234,'ABC')